# Is Photoshop possible on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, photoshop

Is it possible to run a full version of Photoshop on Ubuntu Touch.  I'm thinking about switching my wife from a standard laptop to a tablet (Nexus 10), but she does a lot of photo editing and I don't want her to be stuck with the limited Photoshop touch version.  Has anyone managed to use the full version on a tablet yet?

Comment: The full version of adobe photoshop is really not that easy to handle without a mouse, be aware of that.

Comment: No, but the good news is, you don't need Photoshop to do photo editing.

Answer (score 0):

At this time Ubuntu Touch is only available as Developer Preview.

Many things do not work yet as they will be on a finalized version. This might be earliest end of 2013 or beginning of 2014.

Till that time it is just meant to give a preview for Developers. They can work on the first apps and on the core system itself to make it work well and to make it look beautifully.

You will have to wait or you will have to check for a device with a different operating system.

Additionally you should try it out before you buy - My personal opinion is, that the use of phontoshop or any other similar program will be completely different on a desktop pc with mouse or graphic tablet than on a tablet computer itself. This is a decision that neets a lot of research.